# Why can't I compute the Tutte polynomial as described in a paper?

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory

I am trying to compute the Tutte polynomial of a graph
as described in a paper and Wikipedia, but don't get experimental support.

[Paper p.9](https://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~andrew/Tutte.pdf) and Wikipedia 
relate the Tutte polynomial of a graph to another polynomial.

If $(x-1)(y-1)=z$, $$T(G;x,y)=F_G(z,y)/H(G)$$

Where $F_G(z,y)=\sum_{A \subseteq E}z^{c(G_A)}(y-1)^{|A|} $
where $c(G)$ is the number of connected components and $H(G)$ has simple
closed form.

> Experimentally I can't compute the Tutte polynomial using this approach. The results for the Tutte polynomial are wrong
>   Why?

For example for $K_3$ the code computes $F_{K_3}=y^3 z-z+1$ and I verified this by hand.

Any bugs in this sagemath program?

```
def tutte_to_hyper(g):
    def ra(g):  return g.order() - g.connected_components_number()
    def cg(g):  return g.connected_components_number()
    def nu(g):  return g.size() - ra(g)
    SS=Subsets(g.edges(0))
    K.<y,z>=QQ[]
    su=0
    rae=ra(g)
    ve=list(g.vertices())
    for S in SS:
        S=list(S)
        #if len(S)==0:  continue
        ve=uniq(flatten(S))
        F=g.subgraph(ve,edges=S)
        su += z**cg(F)*(y-1)**len(S)
    return su,(y-1)**ra(g)*z**cg(g)
```

Comment: I don't know sagemath, so can't comment on the code. But what do you mean with "I can't compute the Tutte polynomial"? Does the program not run, or does it get an incorrect result?
From your remarks about $x=1$ implying $z=0$: It looks like $F$ and $H$ are defined such that $F$ contains terms of the form $z^{c(G_A)}f(y)$ and $H$ is a product of $z^{c(G)}$ and a term not containing $z$. Since $c(G_A) \ge c(G)$ that quotient is guaranteed to be a polynomial in $z$, but of course if you set $z=0$ and try to compute the actual values of $F(y,z)$ and $H(y,z)$ you get 0 and can't devide them.

Comment: @Ingix I mean I get incorrect result for the Tuttte polynomial when I implemented the algorithm in the paper.

Comment: Do you have a simple example (pref. 3 or less vertexes) where you get incorrect results? A triangle or a path of length 2, for example? If the code is wrong, I can't help you, but it usually helps with debugging.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks. Edited with computation about $K_3$.

Comment: @Ingix I verified the computation for $K_3$ by hand. Misinterpretation of something is possible.

Comment: To compare understanding, my result is $F_{K_3} (y,z) =z^3+3z^2(y-1)+3z(y-1)^2+z(y-1)^3$, which is obviously different from what the program does.

Comment: When you continue from len(S)=0, that is IMO incorrect as for the empty subset you get the term $z^3$ in my calculation. Also, I have no idea how the program knows when the end of the for loop is supposed to be. But again, I've no idea of sagemath.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks. I don't continue after len(S)=0, it is commented. Possible problem is the number of connected components of the empty graph (the graph on zero vertices). In you computations which value for it you take?

Comment: From my understanding in wikipedia, you *never* change the vertex set for your graph, you *only* change the edge set. So if the edge set $A$ is empty, in case of the $K_3$ you get 3 vertices, no edges, so 3 components. This may be the reason you are not getting exponents of z higher than 1. This is also the definition in your paper, on page 7. "Let G = (V, E) be a graph and $A \subseteq E$. Identify A with the spanning subgraph $G_A$ = (V, A)." The vertex set of $G_A$ is still the complete V.

Comment: @Ingix Many thanks. After this change (commenting one line) I get correct results :) Will accept this as answer.. You may also consider answering https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306379/can-we-efficiently-count-modulo-2-the-number-of-connected-subgraphs-of-a-planar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding in wikipedia, you never change the vertex set for your graph, you only change the edge set. So if the edge set $A$ is empty, in case of the $K_3$ you get 3 vertices, no edges, so 3 components. This may be the reason you are not getting exponents of $z$ higher than 1. This is also the definition in your paper, on page 7. "Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph and $A \subseteq E$. Identify $A$ with the spanning subgraph $G_A = (V, A)$." The vertex set of $G_A$ is still the complete $V$.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to imply efficiently counting spanning connected subgraphs modulo 2 of planar graphs. Get experimental support for it, asked at: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306379/can-we-efficiently-count-modulo-2-the-number-of-connected-subgraphs-of-a-planar